# Where does the barrel come from in which Bombur jumps in The Hobbit: DoS?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, the-desolation-of-smaug

Just saw the second part of the Hobbit. I wonder in which barrel Bombur jumps in "Barrel down the River" scene. All the Dwarves are in their barrels floating and fighting of the Orcs then miraculously Bombur hops out of the water crushes a lot of Orcs and then fights some more even after his barrel is broken. After that over-the-top fighting scene, he  jumps back in the river in an apparently empty barrel.

But if I recall correctly all the barrels were filled when Bilbo dropped them in the water. There was no empty barrel (otherwise Bilbo should have crawled in the empty one eventually). On the other hand, I highly doubt PJ and the writers would have made such a stupid error, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Honestly, this was the part that bugs me most about the movie. definitely deserves a +1.

Comment: Gotta love unexplained downvotes.

Comment: I don't remember if all of the barrels were occupied by dwarves. But I think that it was Kili's barrel..

Comment: Also, when they get on the barge to lake town, there is a barrel for Bilbo to hide in, despite him not starting the river ride in one.

Comment: If they could create Tauriel out of thin air for the movie, why not an extra barrel or two?

Comment: @Smorgasbord Well, there's always room for another beautiful woman in a movie ;) Now, barrels on the other hand... It's gotta be something that we have missed

Comment: @Alexander this makes total sense why not post as answer? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard And where does Kili jumps into then?

Comment: @BramVanroy Kili is wounded and I thought he spent some time out of his barrel at some point to see to his wound while the others are still rolling. I might be mistaken though, need to see that again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard All very wll possible, but *eventually* they all arrive in barrels at Bard's dock/boat. (The one exception possibly being Bilbo.)

Comment: @BramVanroy true, but maybe there were two in one barrel?

Comment: A related question would be in which barrel *Bilbo* hides when they are smuggled into *Esgaroth* (but maybe they got on additional one from *Bard* or the guy he gets the fish from).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this question has been unanswered long enough. I call **movie mistake!**

I'll use two different articles to defend my claim. Firstly, [this article](http://www.stuff.co.nz/marlborough-express/news/6090867/Hobbits-elude-us-but-we-get-to-set) describes the primary filming location -  The Pelorus River.

However, a second article I've found involves an interview with Peter Jackson about the creation of this scene. This was Peter Jackson had to say:

> **How tough was it to shoot the centerpiece action sequence with the
>   barrels?**
>
> **Jackson**: We had these big V8 water-jet things that we
>   built on a circle – it was like a theme park – about as big as this
>   room. And we were worried because we thought, how fast can we actually
>   grind, wind the engine up, because we could sort of wind it up at
>   speed and, you know, we’d better be careful, you know, because we
>   don’t know quite, it’s gonna be unpredictable and it was. And we had
>   stunt guys doing it, round and round, and testing it and everything
>   else, but you know, these are actors, they’re a little bit fragile
>   (laughter). But by the end of the first day, the guys were just
>   yelling, “Faster! Faster! Get it faster, faster, faster!” And we had
>   it on max, we had the thing going on maximum pretty quickly.
>
> *But one of the things that doesn’t really get referenced in the
>   barrels is we also did another shoot on a different river in New
>   Zealand, called the Awatere River in the North Island.* And that was a
>   shoot where – that’s a particular river, it’s like a gorge or a
>   canyon, a rocky canyon that stretches about a mile and right at the
>   head of the canyon is a big dam, and four times a day they open up the
>   sluice gates and they just let this enormous torrent of water out, and
>   they let it out for 10 minutes and then they close the gates again.
>   *And so we got a lot of the really kind of hair-raising barrel stuff in
>   the Awatere.* It would be too dangerous to put a stunt guy down. I
>   mean, we didn’t even dare put anyone in the barrels. We sent the
>   barrels down completely empty and we put the digital Dwarves in later.
>   But that got some of the more dramatic footage, was this – and it was
>   just, it was great because we could set up the cameras when it was dry
>   in between the dumps and we set up about six cameras right the way
>   down the length of the gorge, and then we were there for about three
>   days and every single, you know, four times a day on the dot, these
>   things would open for 10 minutes. And we had a team up, throwing the
>   barrels in, at the top. And we had another guys – you didn’t know what
>   the hell was gonna happen to them, you had just to – they just were
>   filmed on the way down and we had a team at the bottom recovering the
>   barrels. We lost three of them. *I mean, to this day, we don’t know
>   where three of those barrels have gone.*

I've italicised a few sections for effect. Effectively, the shoot was done in multiple locations, on multiple days, involving fast moving water, with the actors later super-imposed in for the most dangerous parts.

Given all this, it seems highly possible that it was a simply **movie mistake**. Whilst now it has been alluded to in this thread (and to me at least, it sticks out like a sore thumb everytime I rewatch the scene), this has been highlighted almost nowhere else online (e.g. [Movie Mistakes](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.moviemistakes.com/&ei=EBIeU8HsMsSmhAedtYGQDw&usg=AFQjCNF25gOE1Y_GGtqDMulymtSkIZ4jlA&sig2=HY-ojtC6zejWsUc-qCO9fQ&bvm=bv.62578216,d.ZG4)). Unless you're really paying attention, it's easy to gloss over which is my assumption as to why it wasn't spotted.

I can provide no definitive evidence, just opinion - it seems very much like a simple movie mistake.

Answer (score -3):

As seen from this clip - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrRhXth2oCQ - there are 13 barrels released into the water.

Comment: And there are 13 Dwarves in the company. So, there's one barrel short if Bombur jumps from one into another.